# Combining two date columns both in the format dd/mm/yyyy with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a df which contains two merged dfs, each containing a date column written as dd/mm/yyyy (not in datetime format).

I want to make them into one date column in the new df, bearing in mind there are times when one of the dfs had a date the other didn't, so there are NaNs where this occurs in the df.

How do I make this one column and combine all these dates into one list?

I don't know what code to use to combine these columns into one, hoping someone will know how!

Comment: You example is unclear, do you have a concatenation as 2 columns, as rows with a common index? You must provide a clear reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how I understood your question. You need to fill in the missing values of one field, using the value of the other field and convert them into a datetime object. This is what I came up with.

```
import numpy as np

# Dummy data
data = {
    'date_a': ["21/12/2023", np.nan, "22/12/2023", "23/12/2023"],
    'date_b': [np.nan, "24/12/2023", np.nan, np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['date_merged'] = df['date_a'].combine_first(df['date_b'])

pd.to_datetime(df['date_merged'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```